# fabric-ca-client error for 4 org system

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting this error while registering new user

```
2017/10/11 07:53:11 [DEBUG] Received request
POST /api/v1/enroll
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5wdw==
{"caName":"","certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\r\nMIHMMHICAQAwEDEOMAwGA1UEAwwFYWRtaW4wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMB\r\nBwNCAASUWo/5gS9H/PSvsiNK2iGsWw0nv7tsVnGG+ZY3cWFJ3ANz6cNmd+lRLZS3\r\nBhHYD/FZhhqwBucMHFE1sB9SqqEnoAAwDAYIKoZIzj0EAwIFAANIADBFAiEAiHjk\r\ncyM3gzqYbLAFVz8kHahVXtAjEOb82q7jiP35Tm4CIAHQsotf2301RCBVQ6i5hb9i\r\nByHhofDyhEFbch7gJVVF\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\r\n"}
2017/10/11 07:53:11 [DEBUG] Directing traffic to default CA
2017/10/11 07:53:11 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity admin
2017/10/11 07:53:11 [DEBUG] Failed to get identity 'admin': sql: no rows in result set
```

I have my own fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file

```
identities:
     - name: admin
       pass: adminpw
       type: client
       affiliation: ""
       maxenrollments: -1
       attrs:
          hf.Registrar.Roles: "client,user,peer,validator,auditor"
          hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "client,user,validator,auditor"
          hf.Revoker: true
          hf.IntermediateCA: true
          hf.GenCRL: true
affiliations:
   org1:
      - department1
      - department2
   org2:
      - department1
      - department2
   org3:
      - department1
      - department2
   org4:
      - department1
      - department2
```

```

I browsed .db file I didn't find any data in any of the table

Comment: From memory, I think that the server likes to create the database initially and then populates it.  This may have changed, but I remember submitting an issue because not all users would have sufficient permissions to create a database (E.g. users on shared hosting platforms).  Anyway, your issue is self explanatory - the server database has not been instantiated and as such there is no admin user.

Answer (score 3):

Deleted fabric-ca-server.db file and keys in keystore restarted ca_Peers and it worked

Comment: Hi Darshu, I met with the same issue..Do you mean go into the ca container and run `rm -rf /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db`..

What you mean by keys in keystore? Is it `/tmp/fabric_*` stuff?

Comment: There wil be a keystore in /tmp directory where private keys are stored you need to delete them inorder to generate new ones